# Python CGI: 500 internal server error, where to find what I did wrong?

Tags: python, cgi, internal-server-error

so I'm trying to test my code and have made quite a few changes but each time I am getting '500 internal server error'. I don't get what I'm doing wrong. I also don't know where I can look for a better description of the error.

Thanks.

Edit: added code at the bottom.

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

new = open("survey.ssv", "r+")
new.write(form.getvalue("surveyQuestion")+"\n")
new.seek(0)
lines = new.readlines()
i = 0

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print "<html>"
print "<head>"
print "<title>Create-a-Survey!</title>"
print "</head>"
print "<body bgcolor='white' text='black'>"
print "<center>"
print "<h1>Create Survey Page</h>"
print "</center>"
print "To create a survey first input a title in the 'Survey Title' text box. To add questions,  write a question in the 'Survey Question' text box and click the 'Add' button. If you want to create a new survey, write a new survey title and click 'New'. The 'Done' button will end the survey creation and return you to the welcome page."
print "<br><br>"

for line in lines:
    if i == 0:
        print "Current Survey Title:<br>%s" % line
        print "<br><br>"
        print '<form action="newSurvey.py" method="post">'
        print 'Survey Title:<br><input type="text" name="surveyTitle">'
        print '<input type="submit" name="decision" value="New">'
        print '</form>'
        print '<br><br>'

    else:
        print "Question %d:<br>%s" % i, % line
        print '<br><br>'
    i = i + 1
new.close()
print '<form action="addQuestion.py" method="post">'
print 'Survey Question:<br><input type="text" name="surveyQuestion">'
print '<br><br>'
print '<input type="submit" name="decision" value="Add">'
print '</form>'
print '<form action="doneSurvey.py" method="post">'
print '<input type="submit" name="decision" value="Done">'
print '</form>'
print '<a href="welcome.html">Back to welcome page</a>'
print '</body>'
print '</html>'
```

This is code that's currently working, and is the one that I end up running before the code above:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()   # enable debugging mode

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

new = open("survey.ssv", "r+")
new.write(form.getvalue("surveyQuestion")+"\n")
lines = new.readlines()
i = 0

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print "<html>"
print "<head>"
print "<title>Create-a-Survey!</title>"
print "</head>"
print "<body bgcolor='white' text='black'>"
print "<center>"
print "<h1>Create Survey Page</h>"
print "</center>"
print "To create a survey first input a title in the 'Survey Title' text box. To add questions,  write a question in the 'Survey Question' text box and click the 'Add' button. If you want to create a new survey, write a new survey title and click 'New'. The 'Done' button will end the survey creation and return you to the welcome page."
print "<br><br>"

for line in lines:
    if i == 0:
        print "Current Survey Title:<br>%s" % line
        print "<br><br>"
        print '<form action="newSurvey.py" method="post">'
        print 'Survey Title:<br><input type="text" name="surveyTitle">'
        print '<input type="submit" name="decision" value="New">'
        print '</form>'
        print '<br><br>'

    else:
        print "Question %d:<br>%s" % i, % line
        print '<br><br>'
    i = i + 1
new.close()
print '<form action="addQuestion.py" method="post">'
print 'Survey Question:<br><input type="text" name="surveyQuestion">'
print '<br><br>'
print '<input type="submit" name="decision" value="Add">'
print '</form>'
print '<form action="doneSurvey.py" method="post">'
print '<input type="submit" name="decision" value="Done">'
print '</form>'
print '<a href="welcome.html">Back to welcome page</a>'
print '</body>'
print '</html>'
```

Comment: Writing to a `r+` file, then reading from it will result in an empty list of lines; seek to the start *first*.

Comment: As for the error, it depends on your web server as to if and where it may have logged more information.

Comment: I added `new.seek(0)`, shown in the code above, and I'm still getting this error.

Comment: It doesn't look like that'd cause the 500 error here, that was just general advice.

Comment: Hey, I removed the variables that follow the print statements and the ampersands corresponding to those variables inside the print statements, and my program seems to work now. Do you have any clue where I went wrong with those variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is not valid Python:

```
print "Question %d:<br>%s" % i, % line
```

If you want to interpolate two values, use a tuple:

```
print "Question %d:<br>%s" % (i, line)
```

Comment: Hey martijn. One last question. it seems like what's already in my file is being overwritten with `form.getvalue("surveyQuestion")`. Do you know why this is? I simply want to append `form.getvalue("surveyQuestion")` to the file

Comment: @user3251142: `'r+'` puts the file pointer at the start of the file; `'a+'` should work (append and read), or use `.seek(0, 2)` to seek to the end first.

Comment: you are a lifesaver, my code is coming together really nicely now :)

Comment: just to understand, so if i use r+ and write 5 digits where in my file there were >5 digits, what would happen? does r+ just always overwrite the file? edit: just tested it and na, they got pushed to the next line. fully understood.

Comment: @user3251142: you are overwriting the first 6 characters in your file with 5 digits and a newline. The previous characters in those 6 positions are lost.